# Why won't my code switch player names correctly after 3 rounds of play?

Tags: c++, debugging

So in my class I had to make a Numberwang simulation game. Everything works fine except for the fact that after 2 rounds the names don't correlate correctly. It supposed to say "Round 3, Player1 to play first." which it does however player2 comes up as the one to play first.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <ctime>
# include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;



bool numberwang(int n)
{
    if(n < 100 ){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;

    }

}
int main()
{
    string Firstplayer, Otherplayer;

    int rounds;
    int  counter = 1;
    int number;
    int win = 18;
    int lose= 1;

    cout << "Hello, and welcome to Numberwang, the maths quiz that simply everyone is talking about!" << endl;

    cout << "What is player 1's name? ";
    cin >> Firstplayer;

    cout << "What is player 2's name? ";
    cin >> Otherplayer;

    cout << "How many rounds? ";
    cin >> rounds;

    cout << "Well, if you're ready, lets play Numberwang!" << endl;


    while(counter <= rounds){
        cout << "Round " << counter << ", " << Firstplayer << " to play first." << endl;
        while(true){
            cout << Firstplayer << ": ";
            cin >> number;

            if(numberwang(number)){
                counter++;
                if(counter > rounds){
                    cout << "That's Numberwang!" << endl;

                    cout << "Final scores: " << Firstplayer << " pulls ahead with " << win << ", and " << Otherplayer << " finishes with " << lose <<  endl;
                    break;
                }

                cout << "That's Numberwang!" << endl;
                swap(Firstplayer, Otherplayer);
                cout << "Round " << counter << ", " << Firstplayer << " to play first." << endl;

            }
            cout << Otherplayer << ": ";
            cin >> number;

            if(numberwang(number)){
                counter++;
                if(counter > rounds){
                    cout << "That's Numberwang!" << endl;

                    cout << "Final scores: " << Firstplayer << " pulls ahead with " << win << ", and " << Otherplayer << " finishes with " << lose <<  endl;
                    break;
                }

                cout << "That's Numberwang!" << endl;
                swap(Firstplayer, Otherplayer);
                cout << "Round " << counter << ", " << Firstplayer << " to play first." << endl;

            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this swapping necessary?  It looks like all you need to do is place the names in an array, and just pick name `array[(counter-1) % 2)]` as the current name.

Comment: Have you tried single stepping through your code with a debugger?  It's a great way to find out why things happen in your program.

Comment: @paul i understand but how would that change the swapping in my code exactly

Comment: @EddieWhite There is no need to swap, and there is no need to have two sets of `if` statements for player 1 and player 2.  Assuming that `turnValue` starts at 1, the current name will always be `string currentName = array[(turnValue - 1) % 2];` and the other player will always be `string otherName = array[turnValue % 2];` and just use currentName and otherName in a single while loop.  And all you need to do is add 1 to `turnValue` instead of swapping.

Comment: @EddieWhite A hint: how many times do you swap the players per round?

Answer (score 1):

After your if-statement (line 61) you say 'Firstplayer' and then you output the 'Otherplayer'. The names do not match.

> Blockquote

```
cout << "Round " << counter << ", " << Firstplayer << " to play first." << endl;

        }
        cout << Otherplayer << ": ";
        cin >> number;
```